# Have you thought use GNU Trove in Netty?

Tags: netty

I really like this project after I tried out a few of the examples. I think you guys are doing a great job on this. Just curious if you have thought of using GNU Trove? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I suspect it would not help to speed netty up futher. Also we try to keep the dependency tree as small as possible. So at the moment you can use netty with "zero" dependencies :)